# How much manufacturing and installing inaccuracy can USB C port tolerate? Is 0.5 to 1 mm too much?

Tags: usb, usb-c, usb-pd

How much manufacturing and installing inaccuracy can USB C port tolerate? Is 0.5 to 1 mm too much?
From recent purchases I found lots of USB C ports on brand new consumer products are not manufactured/installed accurately. Most of them are from reputable/top brands and their official or authorized stores.
To be specific, things are not in their supposed shape. Parts that supposed to be symmetrical are not symmetrical, some supposed flat surfaces have some degree of curvature in it, port is not centered in the opening, the plastic piece that has metal contacts on it is not flat/straight or centered in the USB C port itself. From eyeballing them I think the inaccuracies are about 0.5 to 1 mm.

The force used on plug/unplug into/from inaccurately manufactured/installed ports is greater than on more accurate ones when using the same male connecters.

Pictures as requested, all are brand new devices from currently supposed top/reputable brands and purchased from their companies' flagship/official/directly owned store:

[image: USB C port example 1]
[image: USB C port example 1 (device flipped)]
USB C port example 1, middle plastic piece and the port itself are not centered in their own ways, shroud not in proper shape, one can use adjacent USB A ports' overall condition as reference during observation.

[image: USB C port example 2]
USB C port example 2, the port is not aligned with the opening properly.

[image: USB C port example 3]
USB C port example 3, middle plastic tongue is curved a little bit, the offset probably is under half a millimeter. But still, there are contacts on both sides, the spring contact on USB C male connecters are relatively small hence have less tolerance I believe.

Comment: citation needed,  but I'd expect the USB standard to very explicitly state tolerances for all these things. 1mm seems to be absurdly much, I'd honestly doubt your eyeballing there.

Comment: Which dimensions are you finding to be off, and in which direction? If the shroud on the receptacle is 1 mm too wide, I would guess that that would be unlikely to cause a problem. If _each contact_ is 1 mm too wide, that would obviously cause a major problem, because the contacts would overlap each other!

Comment: @retardate Can you provide pictures?

Comment: That's the plastic enclosure being off, not the connector. Pick&place machines can place with much higher accuracy than cheaper mold.

Comment: All kinds of dimensions/directions.   I've added pictures as requested. Then it's must due to planned obsolescence.

Answer (score 3):

The [relevant standard](https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-type-cr-cable-and-connector-specification-release-22) specifies all tolerances.

To make it short: a plug that's misaligned by half a millimeter is **Far** from compliant and might damage things, and 1 mm would definitely not work.

Comment: It might still works, but definitely not good for long term reliability. There are wiggle rooms after connectors plugged into ports. The plastic tongue in the middle is flexible, the metal pieces are also got some flexibility in them. Some of the contacts are springs.

Comment: the USB-C shrouding only has 1.7mm air between the middle connector "tongue" and the shroud. I honestly don't see how it *could* work.

Comment: I added some picture examples,  any thoughts?

Comment: yeah, the internal tolerances would eyeball to be barely-within-specs, so much less than 0.5mm, and the mismatch between connector position and hole in enclosure doesn't matter at all

Comment: I have concerns about the contacts not properly pressed together or not having enough surface area in contact with each other. The not centred plastic tongue will cause one of the sides to receive less pressure than the other if not alright unable to make contact, the mismatched port and enclosure opening could result similar effects. The curved middle tongue will have less pressure on some areas if not completely unable to make contact on those areas, because the opposite surfaces it pressed upon are flat.

Comment: I've seen buyer reviews about USB C port's tongue fall off while the said port is used for high wattage PD charging.

Comment: Ok I'll stop this here. There's nothing really off -center about the tongues. You're exaggerating things.

Comment: Because of the shape and alignment of the tongue and shroud, the size of the air gaps on the opposite sides of the tongue are different and their shapes are asymmetrical no? And from my observation, in comparison, USB C ports on the phones don't have these kinds of problems, at least not as obvious, and a USB C hub I purchased recently also don't have these problems and it's the cheapest product among them, it's much cheaper.